# Is there a difference between A112.18.1 and A112.18.1M (both 2.5gpm) shower heads?

Tags: shower, water-pressure

[image: A112.18.1]

[image: A112.18.1M]

Also, what does this practically mean when it comes to shower heads?

Comment: It's for Australia. [Coriolis effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnB4qMT5R_Y)  :) :)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is probably best answered by Moen. Do be aware of the Coriolis effect; you'll find you need to lean to the left when showering south of the equator. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.